# Cloud-based or local network storage

Tags: user-account

Maybe I'm just not looking on the correct pages for this issue.  Once I download and set up a CiviCRM database, is the actual data saved to a cloud?  Or, can I save it all to me local drive or network?

Thanks, G

Comment: It seems not a matter of civicrm as an installable CMS driven CRM system where you store your DBs. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to CiviCRM documentation, section on installation here https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest, CiviCRM database is stored on your hard drive or local network depending on your setup

Answer (score 1):

You can install CiviCRM either on a local server or on a web server off-premise ("the cloud") - off-premise is more common, but not the only option.  Note that CiviCRM is web-based software, like WordPress - so you need a web server to run it on.  Unless you maintain a server yourself, cloud-based is a much simpler option.